# Local breweries and specialty brew in Montreal?

Tags: breweries, specialty-beers, local

Are there local breweries / microbreweries in Montreal, Canada?

What are the specialty brews in Montreal? Is there a must-drink beer in Montreal?

Comment: Unibroue is one of my all-time favorite breweries, and they're in Chambly, just outside of Montreal.  If you like Belgian styles, you must definitely try some of their wares.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The province of Québec is very fertile in microbreweries. Montréal being the major city, has lots to offer. A lot of the beers are available throughout the province, however some are only available at the microbrewery itself, especially seasonal beers - a good reason to visit them! here's a list of the best microbreweries and some of their speciality beers:

**Dieu du Ciel!** (29 Laurier ouest St.)

Must try beer: La Fumisterie - edging on an English/German Ale, with a light caramelized taste. Brewed with biological hemp seeds.

---

**Brasseurs de Montréal** (1483 Ottawa St.)

Must try beer: La Chi orientale - a white beer with light ginger and citronella aroma.

---

**L’amère à boire** (2049 Saint-Denis St.)

Must try beer: La Odense - a Porter with a light smoked caramel perfume.

---

**Benelux** (245 Sherbrooke Ouest St.)

Must try beer: La Moka - A Porter with a bitter chocolate taste with a touch of espresso.

---

**Brutopia** (1219 Crescent St.)

Must try beer: La Raspberry Blonde - A blond beer with a touch of raspberry.

---

**HELM Brasseur-gourmand** (273 Bernard Ouest St.)

---

**Le Réservoir** (9 Duluth Est St.)

---

**Le Cheval Blanc** (809 Ontario est St.)

Must try beer: the classic Cheval Blanc white beer with a slice of orange.

---

**Les 3 brasseurs** (4 breweries on Sainte-Catherine St., Crescent St., Saint-Denis St. and Saint-Paul St.)

Must try beer: La Belle Province - with a touch of maple syrup.

---

*Other breweries in Montréal:*

- Brasserie Bierbrier
- Bistro-Brasserie Les Soeurs Grises
- Brasserie McAuslan
- Brasseurs sans gluten
- Broue pub brouhaha
- L'amère à boire
- La Succursale
- Le Réservoir
- Le Saint-Bock brasserie artisanale
- Les brasseurs RJ
- PolyBroue

Cheers!

Comment: I'm drinking`la bella province`, and it's Lovely!!!

Answer (score 2):

Dieu du Ceil is a brewery and pub in Montreal with several unique beers available that do not get packaged and distributed. Several beers made by Dieu du Ciel are distributed widely across the US, but are usually only available in specialty stores.